# How to increase the height of matplotlib “table” plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot some tables in matplotlib, but for the supblots in this case the table height is too small, how to fill the lower supblot with table?

**Problem: The second row table subplot is too small in height,how to increase it's height**

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(24,28))

# buy
ax[0].bar([1,2,3,4,5],[100,200,300,400,500])
ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)

# table
colors = list('rrrbb')
ax[1].table(cellText=list('abcde'),
            rowLabels=list('abcde'),
            loc='center',
            rowColours=colors,
            cellColours=np.array(colors).reshape(-1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set [`.scale`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/table_api.html#matplotlib.table.Table.scale)

```py
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(14, 14))

# buy
ax[0].bar([1,2,3,4,5],[100,200,300,400,500])
ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)

# table
colors = list('rrrbb')
table = ax[1].table(cellText=list('abcde'),
            rowLabels=list('abcde'),
            loc='center',
            rowColours=colors,
            cellColours=np.array(colors).reshape(-1,1))

ax[1].set_title('Scale (1, 4)')

table.scale(1, 4)
```

### Scale (1, 4)

[image]

### Scale (1, 1)

[image]

Comment: The number inside rows (a,b,c,d,e) are still too small. Can they also be larger?

Comment: @usermay14 maybe `table.set_fontsize(24)`